# Отправить данные POST запросом и получить ответ GET в Delphi

Tags: delphi, post, delphi-7, get

Как отправить запрос (скорее всего это будет POST) на сайт и получить ответ (к примеру GET) объясните пожалуйста синтаксис таких отправок как правильно это делать?

Получать GET запросом страницу я могу и получать с нее нужные данные, а вот отправлять данные на форму сайта и получать результат не умею, если можно примерчик какой то объяснениями напишите.

Comment: можно более подробно. вроде простая веш но не понятно что нужно

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: код как пример напишите как отправить ссылку и получить зашифрованную ссылку

Comment: @Игнат я повторю то, что написал в ответе. "Код как пример" можно написать, когда **вы** выберете, с какими сетевыми компонентами будете работать. Нет какого-то общего примера, поскольку все библиотеки имеют свои отличия. Пример кода должен опираться на **конкретную** библиотеку, причем часто - даже будет зависеть от **версии** этой библиотеки.

Comment: @Игнат помимо прочего - в вашем комментарии вы пытаетесь расширить свой вопрос. Чтобы получить зашифрованную ссылку с указанного сайта нужно будет разбирать содержимое ответа, т.к. ссылка придет как часть html-страницы. Это тема отдельного обсуждения.

Answer (score 4):

[GET](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#GET) и [POST](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#POST) - это виды запросов от клиента, отличающиеся способом передачи информации на сервер. GET-запрос имеет ограничения на длину передаваемой информации (зависит от настроек сервера), POST обычно считается безлимитным (на самом деле это, конечно, не так).

Какой из видов запросов необходимо отправить на сервер - определяется самим сервером. Некорректные виды запросов, а так же запросы с некорректными (с точки зрения сервера) параметрами будут отклонены с сообщением кода ошибки (обычно [400 Bad Request](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP))

Итого, чтобы отправить данные и получить ответ, вам необходимо:

1. Просмотреть исходный код страницы с формой, отправляющей параметры
   (поведение которой вы хотите эмулировать) и понять, какие параметры
   (наименования и тип) и каким запросом (GET или POST) отправляются.
2. Определиться, какие компоненты для HTTP-обмена вы будете
   использовать. Наиболее распространенными для VCL приложений являются
   Indy, ICS (Internet Component Suite), Synapse, встроенные
   (System.Net). Для FireMonkey альтернативы практически нет: до XE7
   включительно только Indy, после - Indy и классы из System.Net.
   Последние - предпочтительнее. Доводов за и против каждой библиотеки
   очень много. Мои личные предпочтения - mORMot для VCL и классы из
   System.Net для FMX. В последних версиях Delphi часть этих
   компонентов доступна через менеджер GetIt
3. После того, как будут выполнены первые два пункта, единственное что
   останется - посмотреть пример использования выбранного набора
   сетевых компонентов применительно к виду запроса.

**Обратите внимание**, что запросы, отправляемые на сайт, часто опираются на [cookie](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie), полученные в результате выполнения предыдущих запросов. Поэтому если (к примеру) тому запросу, который нужно выполнить из приложения, на сайте предшествует авторизация, то сперва вам нужно выполнить ее, в противном случае сайт может отклонить не-авторизованный запрос.

**В дополнение** к предыдущему замечанию: куки, полученные вашим приложением недоступны в браузере. Поэтому если вы (опять-таки, к примеру) авторизовались на сайте запросом из приложения, то браузер об этом не узнает из-за отсутствия у него нужных данных.

Comment: Дополню - используйте браузер Chrome, инструменты разработчика, вкладка сеть - чтобы посмотреть - какие запросы отправляет браузер. Плюс WireShark позволит заглянуть под капот тому, что будет отправлять программа. Поможет просто разместить успешный запрос и неудачный рядом и найти различия :)

Comment: В FireFox тоже можно посмотреть что и куда передаётся (по `F12`). Не хромом единым...

Comment: @zed , АлексейПрисяжный. Давайте не будем мериться любимыми браузерами. Все они имеют средства отладки, включая IE, Opera12 и т.п. Это исключительно дело личных предпочтений.